# Including rails controller action in concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to add a controller action via a concern?

I am trying to include a controller action via concern but it is not getting found:

```
module Wizbang
  module ActsAsWizbang
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do

      def foo
        # do something
      end
    end
end
```

I've added the approprioate route to my routes file, but it can't find the action on the controller.

When I include this code in my controller

```
class SimpleController < ApplicationController

  include Wizbang::ActsAsWizbang

end
```

I receive the message:

`The action 'foo' could not be found for SimpleController.`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define methods to mix into the class, just define them in the module. They don't go inside an `included` block:

```
module Wizbang
  module ActsAsWizbang
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def foo
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried this, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: If it's supposed to be a class method (which is what the error suggests), don't you have to wrap the `def foo` block in a `module ClassMethods` block?

Comment: @SteveRowley The error message does **not** suggest that. Controller actions must be instance methods, not not class methods. The error message indicates that there is no instance method `foo` defined on `SimpleController`.

Comment: It looks like the method is defined (and even callable), but it is not being recognized as an action, _find_action_name is returning nil, which causes the error.  I'm not sure how to correctly register it.  This is the call that is returning incorrectly: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/action_methods/class  I suspect that this is a concerns bug.  I've worked around it by implementing action_missing in my concern instead, which seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your include statement resolves correctly.

I got down this rabbit hole recently, but my problem wasn't that I was doing the concern wrong - it was because the include statement that I was using was not correct, but that error was somehow swallowed and I saw this instead. I ended up with something like the following, but your case may vary.

```
module Api::V1::Concerns
  module Foo
    extend ActiveSupport::Concerns
...


module Api::V1::Bar
  class BazController < ActionController::API
    include Api::V1::Concerns::Foo
```